# Unable to click anything inside of webpack-dev-server screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

We have a React js site that uses the webpack-dev-server component. When I load the regular version of the site, everything seems to work fine. The problem is that when I load the webpack-dev-server version, I am unable to click on any elements on the screen.
After a little debugging, it looks like it is caused by the -index of the overlaying iframe being set to -1.

[This thread](https://github.com/haadcode/orbit/issues/75) seems to be the same issue, but their solution of changing the "inline" property to true doesn't fix anything for me.

Has anyone else had issues like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue for the exact same reason.

I followed your link and it seems like their webpack-dev-server configuration is handled differently than vanilla webpack.

In order to get the webpack-dev-server running in `inline` mode, the webpack configuration should have something similarly to:

```
webpackConfig.devServer = {
  inline: true
}
```

As far as I can tell, the webpack dev server will change it's entry from `localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server` to `localhost:8080/` and provide the live reloading script in the bundled JavaScript files.

In my case, I wanted my example page (`~/index.html`) to be interactive. Regardless of the `inline` mode setting, I can just go to `localhost:8080/index.html`. However, with `inline` mode enabled, the page auto-reloads on source code changes (all notifications are provided via the dev console).

Answer (score 1):

This strange bug is affecting a project using nextjs version 7.0.2.

Setting the webpack config did not work.

We've fixed it with this hack:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && typeof window !== undefined) {
  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  var targetNode = window.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
        var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
        if (iframe && iframe.style.zIndex > -1) {
          iframe.style.zIndex = Math.min(-iframe.style.zIndex, -2);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(targetNode, config);

  // Later, you can stop observing
  // observer.disconnect();
}
```